# Chemscheme package, problem lines above and below scheme, caption above instead of below

Tags: captions

I am trying to use the package chemscheme. I have already used it in other reports working great however this time it is doing something I don't want. There are lines above/below the scheme and the caption is above the scheme instead of below. I think it is interfering with something else but I can't figure it out.

Here is the code for the scheme and a picture:
[image: Picture of problem]

[Problem: lines above, below and caption above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zkC5.png)

```
\begin{scheme}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{RD_Part/RD_2.png}
\caption{Synthesis of Boc-(2-(2-methoxyethoxy)ethyl)-L-serine (2)}
\label{sch:RD_2} 
\end{scheme}
```

Here is the preamble code (It's a bit of mess, sorry):

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle, bookmarks=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=false, breaklinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfborderstyle={}, backref=false, colorlinks=false] {hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[lmodern]{quotchap}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\raggedbottom 

\def\fillandplacepagenumber{%
 \par\pagestyle{empty}%
 \vbox to 0pt{\vss}\vfill
 \vbox to 0pt{\baselineskip0pt
   \hbox to\linewidth{\hss}%
   \baselineskip\footskip
   \hbox to\linewidth{%
     \hfil\thepage\hfil}\vss}}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abbreviations}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{2.5cm}

\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\onehalfspacing
\geometry{verbose, tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm}
%\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\makeindex

\newcommand\myemptypage{ % use this one for inserting blank page
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-2}
    \newpage
    }


\begin{document}
\textbf{\thispagestyle{empty}}



\input{input/cover}

\input{input/abstract}
\input{input/acknowledgement}
\input{input/abbrivitations.tex}



\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\input{content}
\pagebreak{}
\input{appendix} 
%\listoftables
%\listoffigures

\input{input/bibliography}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I tried different versions of the code and excluding some packages but nothing changed.
I would be very thankful for help. :)

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: The scheme is returned as you would like without the lines and the caption underneath the scheme when I comment out `\usepackage{algorithm}`. So, somehow that package is interfering with the setting of the caption.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I also had to exclude the package \usepackage{algpseudocode} and now it works. :)